# xtext: How to use unknown types for generics in the JVM inferrer?

Tags: java, xtext

When I try to use unknown types in the `JvmModelInferrer` it works for simple types, but does not work for generic types.

Example:

```
        val unknownRef = typeRef('com.tmtron.ex.xtext2.usage.Unknown')
        members += domainObject.toField('simpleField', unknownRef)
        val listRef = typeRef(typeof(List), unknownRef)
        members += domainObject.toField('list', listRef)
```

Note: the type `com.tmtron.ex.xtext2.usage.Unknown` does not exist in the target project.

The generator will produce this code:

```
  private com.tmtron.ex.xtext2.usage.Unknown simpleField;

  private /* List<com.tmtron.ex.xtext2.usage.Unknown> */Object list;
```

So the generated code for the `simpleField` is correct (or at least what I expected).
But for the generic `list` the code that I expected is commented out, and `Object` is used instead.

Why does this happen / how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typeRef('java.util.List<com.tmtron.ex.xtext2.usage.Unknown>')` should work as expected in this case.